# Does anyone have this book or know where it can be found [Loève, M. Probability theory. Van Nostrand, New York (1960).]?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm reading "A pair of complementary theorems on convergence rates in the law of large numbers." by Heyde, C. C., & Rohatgi, V. K.

and the following book is cited on page 5/76 : Loève , M. Probability theory. Van Nostrand, New York (1960).

I only need to see page 245 of that book, it's supposedly covering materials about the symmetrized random variables $X^s$ and the weak symmetrization inequalities.

I tried looking everywhere and I couldn't find a way to check out that book, I only found Probability Theory I (1977) and Probability Theory II (1978) by the same author but none of them cover the notions of the two things mentioned above.

I'm hoping that some user here own this book and they would be able to share with me page 245 of it.

Or if you can recommend me something else that would cover the same topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the book republished by Dover - it's in print.

Comment: did you mean to share a link when making that reply by any chance?

Comment: found it, yep looks to be the same book.